# API to ask EF Core DBContext to ignore some AutoIncluded entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

EF Core 7

In the DBContext class, in UpdateNavigationLoading, I have some AutoIncludes

```
private static void UpdateNavigationLoading(ModelBuilder modelBuilder){
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().Navigation(order => order.OrderItems).AutoInclude();
    modelBuilder.Entity<OrderItem>().Navigation(orderItem => orderItem.Item).AutoInclude();
    ... etc
}
```

But in one of my API calls, I do not wish to include the **Item** entity to be returned withe any OrderItem records.

In the **base** service, I eventually basically end up at:

```
return context.Set<Order>().AsQueryable();
```

Beyond this, to that returned IQuerable from AsQueryable(), I add some where clauses, etc, like:

```
if (StartDate.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(item => item.Created >= filter.StartDate);
}
```

or add a limit:

```
if (Limit.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Take(Limit.Value);
}
```

and you can imagine more, I'm sure..

but because of what's in the modelbuilder UpdateNavigationLoading call, the OrderItem's Item  Entity is autoincluded.

Without changing the UpdateNavigationLoading call, is there a way I can indicate to, or ask, the DBContext at the API service level to **not** honour the AutoInclude of the OrderItem.Item?

So in my call to

> context.Set().AsQueryable();

or before that call, can I set something in the DBContext to do what I need?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#model-configuration-for-auto-including-navigations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In EF Core 7, there is no direct built-in functionality to ignore or disable specific auto-included entities at the API service level without modifying the `UpdateNavigationLoading` method. However, you can achieve the desired behavior by using a combination of `Include` and `IgnoreAutoIncludes` methods.

Here's an example of how you can modify your API service code to exclude the `Item` entity from being auto-included for `OrderItem`:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

// ...

public IQueryable<Order> GetOrders(DbContext context, DateTime? startDate, int? limit)
{
    var query = context.Set<Order>().AsQueryable();

    // Apply custom filters
    if (startDate.HasValue)
    {
        query = query.Where(item => item.Created >= startDate);
    }

    if (limit.HasValue)
    {
        query = query.Take(limit.Value);
    }

    // Disable auto-includes temporarily
    query = query.IgnoreAutoIncludes();

    // Include only necessary entities
    query = query.Include(order => order.OrderItems).ThenInclude(orderItem => orderItem.PropertyA)
                 // Add more includes if needed
                 // .Include(order => order.OtherEntity)

    return query;
}
```

In the code above, we first call `IgnoreAutoIncludes` on the `IQueryable<Order>` object to disable auto-includes for subsequent queries. Then, we use the `Include` method to explicitly specify the entities you want to include. By not including the `Item` entity, it won't be auto-included when fetching `OrderItem` records.

Remember to adjust the `Include` calls based on your entity structure and relationships.

Note: The `IgnoreAutoIncludes` method is not available in EF Core 5 or earlier versions. It was introduced in EF Core 6. So, if you are using an older version, this approach won't work, and you may need to modify the `UpdateNavigationLoading` method or consider other alternatives.

Comment: thanks - but you could just run the Includes immediately after the IgnoreAutoIncludes statement no? You don't need a separate line to specify ignore and a new line for any includes you want?

Comment: Yes, you can definitely accomplish that as well. The `IgnoreAutoIncludes` method returns an `IQueryable<T>`, allowing you to chain additional methods to it. I chose to demonstrate my approach in order to provide a clearer example.